# how to get the values not repeated in the list? (Dart - Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two lists:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,4,5]
```

I want to get the values from list `a` that do not exist in list `b`:

```
result = [2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to achieve that and which one fits your situation depends on your requirements (which are not specified in the question).

Do you want to preserve duplicates in `a` or not:

```
a = [1,2,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,4,5]
```

Should this result in `[2,3]` or `[2,2,3]`?

If you do not want to preserve duplicates you can convert your lists to `Set`s and use the [`difference`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Set/difference.html) method:

```
result = a.toSet().difference(b.toSet())
```

Our if you want to preserve the duplicates just `filter` the list.

```
result = a.filter((v) => b.contains(v))
```

Comment: `a` didn't have any duplicates. And I think you meant:

`result = set(a).difference(set(b))`